# Binding breakpoints in VSCode with Nextjs using Typescript with a src directory

Tags: typescript, next.js, vscode-debugger

I've a Nextjs project using Yarn and Typescript and am trying to debug it using VSCode. The root project folder contains front and back folders, with the Nextjs project sitting in the front folder, and the source files in front/src, with the compiled files going into front/dist.  I'm currently unable to set breakpoints and can't work out why. If I hover over the breakpoints while the debugger is running it says "Unbound breakpoint".

I initially tried the instructions at on the Nextjs [website](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging), but these didn't work, so I've tried all sorts of configurations that build on them, but with no success.

My tsconfig.json (in /front):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

My launch.json (in /.vscode):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/front",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - front/tsconfig.json",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/front/dist/*",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/front/dist/*"
      },
      "command": "npm run dev"
      // "command": "yarn dev"
      // "command": "${workspaceFolder}/front/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next ./src"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/front",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/front",
      "request": "launch",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/front/dist/*",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/front/dist/*"
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - front/tsconfig.json",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      // "command": "yarn dev",
      // "command": "${workspaceFolder}/front/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next ./src",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My tasks.json (in /.vscode):

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "front/tsconfig.json",
      "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
      "group": "build",
      "label": "tsc: build - front/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried about every option I've seen on Stackoverflow (you can see the stuff that's commented/added in launch.json), but none of it has worked so far.